# Is it possible to use correlations between variables at different waves but with different participants to fix error variances in SEM?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I am interested in analyzing data from the World Values Survey; the WVS has different waves, however each wave has a single time point. Participants are not the same between waves but the survey questions overlap to a large degree.

I am primarily interested in analyzing relationships between individual questions (i.e., not scales). I was debating whether SEM might be good a fit for my research questions, and so I would need to fix the error variances in order to have enough degrees of freedom.

I know it's possible to fix the error variances using survey items' test-retest reliability, but this would require longitudinal data, which is not applicable in my case.

Consequently, I was wondering if it is appropriate to use the correlation between the same variable at different waves in order to fix the error variances.

For example, say I have latent variable X which is associated with a single manifest variable X. Could I use the correlation between X at wave 1 and wave 2 to fix the error variance of X?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to classical test theory, the error variance Var(error) associated with a test score variable is given as

Var(error) = Var(variable) * (1 - reliability).

A test-retest correlation typically is *not* a good estimate of reliability. (Only under very strict/unrealistic conditions would a test-retest correlation equal reliability.) The test-retest correlation typically underestimates the reliability of a variable, leading to an overestimation of the error variance when using it in the above formula. Perhaps a more appropriate reliability estimate could be derived from a different source.